# How can I fix this error related to int[] numArray?

Tags: c#, .net

Here is a code example that is throwing a compiler error for me and I don't know how to fix it. The error is "Local Variable NumArray might not be initialized before accessing". I do know that I am using old VB Utils CopyArray method. Would like to fix the error and have solution on using C# Array.Copy method.

```
int[] numArray = { };

for (int i = 0; i <= num7; i++)
{

   If(!somecondition)
     {
        path = @"no";
     }
     else
     {
        path = @"yes";
        index++;
        ((int[])Utils.CopyArray(numArray, new int[index + 1]))[index] = i;
     }
}
```

Comment: You should initialize the array (assign it a value).

Comment: numArray = new int[] and put size in bracket...

Comment: @Abhiverma what if he doesn't know the size? Plus, it's not necessary to give a size.

Comment: Then dynamic array can be use and also the error is related to non -initialisation of object not size.

Comment: I updated the code to fix the compiler error. But it appears the CopyArray method is not adding elements to the NumArray array.

Comment: Do we have `Utils.CoppyArray` in C#? Try `Array.Copy`. But I don't know why you you use `Array.Copy` when you need to add something to an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared `numArray` incorrectly. The correct way is:

`int[] numArray = new int[] {};`

Arrays in C# are objects, thus you must call their ctor when initializing them.

Comment: This is not entirely true. `int[] numArray = { };` is valid syntax depending on the C# Version.

Comment: @CSharpie I did not know that.

Comment: @CSharpie, I am compiling this is on .NET 4.7.2.

Comment: @UWPLTD its not the .net-Framework version, but the Version of C#. Should be Version 6 (Visual Studio 2015) or upwards

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably that you forgot to handle the return value of `CopyArray` which is the new  array.

So Change this line

```
   ((int[])Utils.CopyArray(numArray, new int[index + 1]))[index] = i;
```

to this:

```
   numArray= (int[]) Utils.CopyArray(numArray, new int[index + 1]);
   numArray[index] = i;
```

That is assuming that `Utils.CopyArray` does what looks like. Though im not sure why anyone would even use that, when we allready have `Array.Copy`.